# Talend - How to create tXMLMap nested loops

Tags: integration, talend

I have the below flow, and I would like the userGroup to be a loop as well according to data that's coming from another database lookup, Can you point me to the best way to approach this?

[image: tXMLMap]
[image: MyFlow]

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have nested loops in tXMLMap. Another way to achieve this is to build your XML by using the tWriteXMLField component where you can use the concept of Group and Loop Elements. In your example, your group element will be User whereas the loop element will be UserGroup. This allows the grouping (first loop) to be based on the User Tag, and the User Group tag will be your looping element (second loop) inside it. I have attached an image of an a sample:

[image]
Hope this helps.